# Getting Physical Ram

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

What would be the preferred way of gathering how much RAM is in each of our 500+ windows (XP and 7) machines with the least amount of effort?

Comment: There's any number of system auditing tools available.

Comment: Can you list a few?

Comment: No, I don't get into that kind of thing any more.  Google provideth, though; "windows hardware audit" looks helpful, for a start.

Comment: I've got to assume any organisation that has 500+ machines already has one of the more popular system management products installed.  Tivoli, SCOM, something like that - which could run audits and provide this info.

Comment: SCOM would be my guess if you have 500+ PCs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would offer two options:

1. The Microsoft Assessment and Planning (MAP) Toolkit (free)
2. System Information for Windows (requires license purchase and scripting; I used this to determine what sticks of RAM (and how many slots) were in about 50 PCs by running it on all system on the network via PSEXEC.  Then a simple FIND command of the resulting data told me all I needed to know, clearly.

However, since your question was with least amount of effort, I'd probably say MAP.

Answer (score 1):

I gather this information (and a whole lot more) as part of the logon script. Each log (one per machine and one per user) is later parsed and the information stored in a database. The relevant part of the (VBS) script, which I copied from some long forgotten source, is:

```
'// Memory Info
objHardwareFile.WriteLine "Memory Information:"
objHardwareFile.WriteLine "==================="
For Each objMem In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\.\root\cimv2").InstancesOf("Win32_PhysicalMemory")
Select Case objMem.MemoryType
    Case 0
        rtype = "Unknown"
    Case 1
        rtype = "Other"
    Case 2
        rtype = "DRAM"
    Case 3
        rtype = "Synchronous DRAM"
    Case 4
        rtype = "Cache DRAM"
    Case 5
        rtype = "EDO"
    Case 6
        rtype = "EDRAM"
    Case 7
        rtype = "VRAM"
    Case 8
        rtype = "SRAM"
    Case 9
        rtype = "RAM"
    Case 10
        rtype = "ROM"
    Case 11
        rtype = "Flash"
    Case 12
        rtype = "EEPROM"
    Case 13
        rtype = "FEPROM"
    Case 14
        rtype = "EPROM"
    Case 15
        rtype = "CDRAM"
    Case 16
        rtype = "3DRAM"
    Case 17
        rtype = "SDRAM"
    Case 18
        rtype = "SGRAM"
    Case 19
        rtype = "RDRAM"
    Case 20
        rtype = "DDR"
End Select
objHardwareFile.WriteLine " Memory Bank: " &  objMem.BankLabel
objHardwareFile.WriteLine " Memory Size: " & objMem.Capacity/1024/1024 & " MB"
objHardwareFile.WriteLine " Memory Speed: " & objMem.Speed & " MHZ"
objHardwareFile.WriteLine " Memory Type: " & rtype
next
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty good (if ghetto) way of doing it (also, nice to see it uses 1024 to a kilo)